# SQL get average of people's jobs' salaries for each country

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008

**Microsoft SQL Server 2008**

A worker lives in some Country, and may have more than one job, with more than one salary.

I want to get the average for each country's individual total salary.

*Tables:*

1) countries(country_id, name)

2) people(ssn, name,country_id)

3) jobs(ssn, job_title, salary)

**[countries]**

- 1, usa
- 2, germany

**[people]**

- 010101, John, 1
- 020202, Lee, 1
- 030303, Harry, 2

**[jobs]**

- 010101, teacher, 3200
- 010101, builder, 1500
- 020202, actor, 45000
- 020202, singer, 200000
- 030303, producer, 120000

### **Needed Query Result:**

*each country's average (for each country) = sum of each worker's total salaries) / number of workers*

*Country - Average Salary*

- usa - 124850
- germany - 120000

Comment: You'll want to use SUM COUNT AND GROUP BY - What version of sql? SQL Server, MySQL, Oracle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
select Salary / count(c.name) AvgSalary, c.Name
from people p
inner join 
(
  select sum(salary) Salary, p.country_id
  from jobs j
  left join people p
    on j.ssn = p.ssn
  group by p.country_id
) sal
  on p.country_id = sal.country_id
left join countries c
  on p.country_id = c.country_id
group by salary, c.Name;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d27ed/11)

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
SELECT c.name, sum(j.salary)/count(distinct p.ssn) as Avg_Sal 
FROM Countries c
INNER JOIN people p ON c.country_id = p.country_id
INNER JOIN Jobs j on p.ssn = j.ssn
group by c.name
```

Answer (score 0):

This will exactly do,

```
with
country as
(select c.country_id,c.name name,p.ssn ssn from countries c,people p where c.country_id=p.country_id),
sal1 as
(select sum(salary) salary,j.ssn ssn from people p,jobs j where p.ssn=j.ssn group by j.ssn)
select country.name,avg(sal1.salary) from sal1,country where sal1.ssn=country.ssn group by country.name;
```

[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d27ed/36)

Using with clause will be more readable and understandable.